# Android and RESTful services

Tags: android

In [Virgil Dobjanschi talk](http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/events/io/2010/sessions/developing-RESTful-android-apps.html) during Google I/O he mentioned using `Services` for doing the fetching and then using a callback to notify the `Activity` when this was completed. He never went into specifics on how to implement this callback and I can't seem to find anything helpful on this topic anywhere.

I think he said that you didn't need to implement binding at all?

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Google I/O 2010 app.](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/) It uses the pattern he was referring to. It uses Option #2 from CommonsWare's answer.

Comment: Thanks! Never realized that app used his method. What he does is pass a listener interface as a parceable, which I didn't even knew was possible.

Answer (score 8):

Option #1: `Service` sends a broadcast `Intent`, which the `Activity` catches via a `BroadcastReceiver` registered via `registerReceiver()`.

Option #2: If the `Activity` is binding to the `Service`, have the `Activity` pass a listener to the `Service`, which the `Service` invokes when the work is complete.

Option #3: `Service` doesn't do much, but the `ContentProvider` calls `notifyChange()` when the data changes, which can ripple back through to the `Activity` and/or its `Cursor` on the data.

Option #4: Singletons, which should be avoided.

...

Option #237: `Service` sends a letter via FedEx to the `Activity`. :-)

...

All that being said, once they release the Twitter app as open source, you'll know for certain what the Twitter app does.

Comment: As per Rponds answer, the Google I/O app passes a listener as a parceable extra. Was that what you meant with option #2 or did you mean full binding?

Comment: No, Option #2 was full binding. Option...umm...#74 was using `ResultReceiver`. Frankly, I am stunned at that choice, since `ResultReceiver` uses AIDL, and we've been told repeatedly not to use that for local operations due to overhead issues. Perhaps there is something special about `ResultReceiver` that I am unaware of.

Comment: Quick follow-up on this: AIDL does not add overhead for local access. They detect that the client and server are in the same process and route things directly. Hence, my fears about `ResultReceiver` are unfounded. For more, see this thread: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/79049af16fde46e8

Answer (score 0):

i think they're talking ab out using AIDL to communicate between the activity & the service...