# Alternatives for Pushing data from an Android Service to an Activity

Tags: android, performance, android-intent, broadcast

I've a service that is receiving UDP data from the network. I want to *push* this data from the service to a UI activity.

One way to do it is using  *broadcast Intents*. What is the *performance overhead* of sending broadcasts frequently from the service to the activities?

Are there any other alternatives for doing this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure of the overhead of Broadcasting Intents but a topic similar to this was [discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114669/android-and-restful-services) a few days ago.