# How can I share an Object between a running Service and Activity

Tags: android

I have an API Object that I made, and I would like to share it between a running Service and various Activities in my app, almost like if I was to make the class static.  How could I go about sharing the created object between the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the best way to do this is to have a class that holds all the information that you want, and to use that class through each activity and service.

Comment: Did you use a Singleton or a `Parcelable` object?

Comment: @Chiggins, Can you please share some more information or any code example ?

Comment: Are you setting the fields static in that class?

Answer (score 1):

You may find the following helpful.

[Binding a Service to an android.app.Activity vs Binding it to an android.app.Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154899/binding-a-service-to-an-android-app-activity-vs-binding-it-to-an-android-app-appl)

[Android Service interacting with multiple activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141632/android-service-interacting-with-multiple-activities)

[Alternatives for Pushing data from an Android Service to an Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149339/alternatives-for-pushing-data-from-an-android-service-to-an-activity)

Comment: Ha ha awesome. I love it when the answer is along the lines of "I'm not trying to be a jerk, but I am going to politely point out that a quick search could likely have been all you needed"