# Analog of startActivityForResult for Service

Tags: android

Despite [similar question was asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848775/use-startactivityforresult-from-non-activity), I have differnet situation: 
My app consists mostly of a background `Service`. I want to start external activities and get results back.

I see several options:

1. Create dummy `Activity` and keep reference to it for using its `startActivityForResult`. This consumes quite a lot of memory, as we know.
2. Use `Broadcast Intents` instead of Android's results infrastructure: ask client activities to broadcast their results before closing. This kind of breaks the idea and not so performance-efficient.
3. Use `Instrumentation` directly - try to copy code from startActivityForResult into my Service.
4. Use Service interfaces - serialize and add `AIDL` connection to the Intent for starting an Activity. In this case Activity should [call Service directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114669/android-and-restful-services) instead of providing result.

The third approach feels closer to Android for me, but I'm not sure if it's possible to do - Service does not have its Instrumentation, and default implementation seems to always return null.

Maybe you have any other ideas?

Comment: It can be achieved with a simple hack , by the use of SharedPreferences ,[SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31461941/4859873)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think option 2 is the most idiomatic way on android. Using `startActivityForResult` from an `Activity` is a synchronous/blocking call, i.e., the parent activity waits and does not do anything until the child is done. When working from a `Service` and interacting with activities your primarily doing asynchronous/non-blocking calls, i.e., the service calls out for some work to be done and then waits for a signal to tell it that it can continue.

If you are using the [android local service pattern](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample) then you can have your activities acquire a reference of the `Service` and then call a specific function after it has performed its work. Attempting your option 3 would be counter to what the framework provides for you.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts! Now I'm choosing between 2 (easier to implement) and 4 (more secure/private and should be faster).

I don't really agree that startActivityForResult is blocking (because it uses callback function, not result value), and also Instrumentation is in public API =)
Thanks!

Comment: I meant it's not blocking in the traditional sense (e.g., a blocking io call). It's blocking in the conceptual manner in which you use it.

Comment: @Qberticus  The link you provided just links to a generic samples page.

Answer (score 22):

I’ve been thinking about this recently when implementing [account authenticators](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AbstractAccountAuthenticator.html) with three-legged authorisation flows. Sending a result back to the service for processing performs better than processing it in the activity. It also provides a better separation of concerns.

It’s not that clearly documented, but Android provides an easy way to send and receive results anywhere (including services) with [`ResultReceiver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ResultReceiver.html).

I’ve found it to be a lot cleaner than passing activities around, since that always comes with the risk of leaking those activities. Additionally, calling concrete methods is less flexible.

To use `ResultReceiver` in a service, you’ll need to subclass it and provide a way to process the received result, usually in an inner class:

```
public class SomeService extends Service {

    /**
     * Code for a successful result, mirrors {@link Activity.RESULT_OK}.
     */
    public static final int RESULT_OK = -1;

    /**
     * Key used in the intent extras for the result receiver.
     */
    public static final String KEY_RECEIVER = "KEY_RECEIVER";

    /**
     * Key used in the result bundle for the message.
     */
    public static final String KEY_MESSAGE = "KEY_MESSAGE";

    // ...

    /**
     * Used by an activity to send a result back to our service.
     */
    class MessageReceiver extends ResultReceiver {

        public MessageReceiver() {
            // Pass in a handler or null if you don't care about the thread
            // on which your code is executed.
            super(null);
        }

        /**
         * Called when there's a result available.
         */
        @Override
        protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
            // Define and handle your own result codes
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                return;
            }

            // Let's assume that a successful result includes a message.
            String message = resultData.getString(KEY_MESSAGE);

            // Now you can do something with it.
        }

    }

}
```

When you start an activity in the service, create a result receiver and pack it into the intent extras:

```
/**
 * Starts an activity for retrieving a message.
 */
private void startMessageActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MessageActivity.class);

    // Pack the parcelable receiver into the intent extras so the
    // activity can access it.
    intent.putExtra(KEY_RECEIVER, new MessageReceiver());

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And finally, in the activity, unpack the receiver and use `ResultReceiver#send(int, Bundle)` to send a result back.

You can send a result at any time, but here I've chosen to do it before finishing:

```
public class MessageActivity extends Activity {

    // ...

    @Override
    public void finish() {
        // Unpack the receiver.
        ResultReceiver receiver =
                getIntent().getParcelableExtra(SomeService.KEY_RECEIVER);

        Bundle resultData = new Bundle();

        resultData.putString(SomeService.KEY_MESSAGE, "Hello world!");

        receiver.send(SomeService.RESULT_OK, resultData);

        super.finish();
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for the solution! one thing:  RESULT_OK should be **-1** according to Activity.java

Comment: Good point. I think in this case it’s possible to use any values, but it’s better to stay consistent with whatever the platform provides. I’ve updated the answer. You could use Activity.RESULT_OK directly as well.

Comment: you need to add `@SuppressLint("ParcelCreator")` before the class `MessageReceiver` otherwise it will ask you to make a CREATOR as [ResultReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ResultReceiver.html) implements Parcelable. Thanks for the answer.