# Share info between two processes - what's the safest way?

Tags: android, process, sharedpreferences, android-broadcast

I have an app with two processes - the `MainActivity` and a background `Service`. I need the same information in both, and this info comes from my server (a JSON response).
I was loading this JSON from both processes, but as this JSON may get bigger it's pretty inefficient to load twice.

What is the  safest or best practice to share this info?

- Broadcast and copy the JSON from `MainActivity` to `Service` - I assume this is a safe practice and my broadcast won't get lost
- Use `SharedPreferences` to store this locally and both consume from this "local" JSON until the app is closed. According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125214/shared-preferences-between-two-processes-of-the-same-application) `SharedPreferences` works fine between processes.

Any other suggestion/recommendation is very appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not using a singlteton class where u share all your data.

Comment: They are in different processes, that's the point. I tried to store it in a static class, but if I close the app my Service can't access it anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most common way is sending a broadcast and also you should avoid using singletons, for more information see this link

[Android and RESTful services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114669/android-and-restful-services)

It's better to take a look at [Event Bus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

As the doc says :

> simplifies the communication between components
>
> - decouples event senders and receivers
> - performs well with Activities, Fragments, and background threads
> - avoids complex and error-prone dependencies and life cycle issues

Comment: Thanks! Seems to be a great solution. I'll implement that then accept your answer